# F# Type Provider SQL Server example

Tags: sql-server, f#, type-providers

I'm reading [Walkthrough: Accessing a SQL Database by Using Type Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/type-providers/accessing-a-sql-database)

and working it through using my test database.  So far, I have done this in F# interactive:

```
#r "System.Data.dll"
#r "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll"
#r "System.Data.Linq.dll"
open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI;">
```

now, I know that this database has a table called test.  e.g. in SSMS:

[image: SSMS select * from sys.tables]

So, you can see that I have a table called "table1".  Continuing with the example I write:

```
let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
let table1 = db.table1
```

But then I get the error:

> error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'table1' is not defined

So, what am I doing wrong here?

FYI: F# Compiler version 11.0.60610.1

Comment: What do you see when you type `db.` - does the completion offer any table names? Are there any other errors anywhere in the file?

Comment: @Tomas when I type db. there is not completion offered.  (Running in F# interactive, I guess it doesn't support auto completion)  No other errors so far

Comment: @Ed db.sys.tables doesn't work: "error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'sys' is not defined" but then sys.tables is a view, not a table.  maybe there's another way to access views?

Comment: @user1443098 I would not be able to write any code directly in F# interactive :-). My recommendation is to get a decent F# editor (Ionide on Mac/Windows or VS on Windows) and write code in a script file - that way, you will get much better feedback.

Comment: F# Compiler version 11.0.60610.1 is really old. Probably F# 3.0?. Can you install VS2015 at least? or VSCode with Ionide. Also for your connection string a) preface it with @, b) specifiy the path to the mdb File: `@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=path/to/mdf/file"`

Comment: Some more information.  If I write: "let table1 = db.Table1" it works, even though the table is called "table1" (all lowercase) and the database uses a case-insensitive collation by default.  I call that a bug in the type provider.  Unfortunately I cannot install VS 2015.  No room on my C: drive.  Also, I don't need to specify the mdb. The connection string is fine.

Comment: FWIW I did the same in VSCode/Ionide but didn't get far.  The exact same code as above gave me an error "error FS0222: Files in libraries or multiple-file applications must begin with a namespace or module declaration, e.g. 'namespace SomeNamespace.SubNamespace' or 'module SomeNamespace.SomeModule'"  which seems bogus to me.  anyway, adding a namespace declaration didn't help.  same error

Comment: oh, so u can connect to the db. in that case u can answer ur own question and accept it. table/Table is not neccesarily a bug. ORMs and typeproviders frequently map names to their own convention. linqpad does pruralise for example.

Answer (score 2):

The FSharp SqlDataConnection type provider erroneously maps tables in a database to names where the first letter is capitalized, regardless of the actual table name.  In my case, the table was called "table1" but the type provider mapped it to "Table1".  This idiosyncrasy is not covered in the documentation.

This is confusing, unexpected and undocumented behavior.

Comment: As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/sqldataconnection-type-provider-%5Bfsharp%5D) mentions, the provider uses SqlMetal.exe to generate the types.  Unfortunately, while SqlMetal provides an option to control pluralization (which is also exposed by the type provider), there is no such option to control capitalization.

Comment: Right,  I'd call that a bug.  Especially when you have to remember to capitalize your table names.  Just imagine that you started with a capitalized name on SQL Server, used it in your code, then changed it to uncapitalized on SQL Server.  Your code will die next time it tries to access it.  I'd recommend that the type provider be case-insensitive for objects from SQL Server. But who to send that to?

Comment: You could file a complaint with MS of course. :-) However please note the top of the doc: `This guide was written for F# 3.0 and will be updated. See FSharp.Data for up-to-date, cross-platform type providers`. This is one of the stock type providers carried over from F# 3.0, it works well with SqlServer, that's true. However you could explore these two type providers that are being continuously developed: [SQLProvider](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/), which works with all kinds of DBs, and [SQLClient](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/) which is SqlServer specific.

Comment: @s952163 Thanks,  I will check out those other two!